# How to use Regular Expressions to replace part of a string in SQLite?

Tags: sql, regex, sqlite

I currently would like some advice on how to find and replace part of a string using regular expressions in SQLite? i am using Rstudio/R as the SQLite connector.

I have the following strings:

```
my_strings
--------------
1244599arts
3490872testing
4478933great
2342340obvious 
gremlin2342678
```

i would like to replace the numbers with the word "final" - now I would like to use regular expressions to achieve this as I want to be able to capture the numbers only and then replace them with the word "final" and not affect any other part of the string

the output i would like to achieve is the following:

```
my_strings
--------------
finalarts
finaltesting
finalgreat
finalobvious 
gremlinfinal
```

As you can see the numbers have now been replaced by the word "final" - please note that I have around 8 million rows so I cannot just repeat a `REPLACE` function as there are simply too many numbers!

I have written some regex to capture those numbers and the following statement will match those numbers:

```
[0-9]{7}
```

[Here is an example of how the above matches those numbers](https://regex101.com/r/BhqxMv/1)

Now I would like to use this regex statement to amend these strings - the reason is that I would like to learn how to use regex in sqlite to find and replace matching parts of a string.

Has anyone got any advice?

for reference, I can use the `REGEXP` function as I have already made a sqlite instance in R.

Comment: I am sorry - but this does not help me - I do not have access to the command line to instal any packages and am only using the RSQLite package - my question is more unique to how this can be solved in sqlite, if there is no alternative to the link you posted above

Comment: Got it. I have removed the suggested duplicate.

Comment: SQLite does not support search-and-replace with the `REGEXP` syntax - it is only used for matching, exactly the same way `LIKE` would be used. For replacing you need to register a separate user function that does that.

Comment: @Tomalak Do you know of any resources for making a user defined function?

Comment: Not sure if that's easily possible. Looking at the `extension-functions.c` in https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite ([link](https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/blob/518156924782a6b90162716d8a16d24fc6663e68/src/vendor/sqlite3/extension-functions.c#L1705)), there seems to be exactly one location that registers extension functions, and it does not register any regex-related functions at all. Which means, you would need to clone that repository, patch it to include a regex-replace function, include it in `RegisterExtensionFunctions`, recompile everything and load your patched sqlite package.

Comment: Opening an issue with the Github repo & waiting until they implement it might work, too.

Comment: Alternative approach is to load the data into R, do your replacements there, and save the modified values back to the database.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for the help - will definitely drop an issue request! I think I may just have to do the cleaning in R then write it back to the database at a later point!

Comment: Other platforms (like Python, for example) offer a way to wire up user-defined functions at runtime, but there seems to be no such facility in the RSQLite package.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for the help! Currently only able to use R at the moment so will try and find a solution here or seek an alternative

Comment: I didn't mean to say "use something else", but rather "SQLite can do this, but the RSQLite package does not implement it", i.e. it's worth to try a making a feature request.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/GeIzr4/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`sqlean-regexp`](https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean/blob/main/docs/regexp.md) extension, which provides regular expressions search and replace functions:

```sql
-- replace 7 digits with the word 'final'
update t set my_strings = regexp_replace(my_strings, '[0-9]{7}', 'final');
```